# Is parse bugged?

Tags: rebol

x below is none instead of {"abdfff} in this very basic parse rule:

```
>> t: {aaa"abdfff"dddddddd}
== {aaa"abdfff"dddddddd}
>>
>> parse t [to {"} copy x to {"}]
== false
>> x
== none
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no expert on rebol, but shouldn't the first `to` be `thru`?

```
parse t [thru {"} copy x to {"}]
```

Does that help?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Other solution can be:
parse t [to {"} skip copy x to {"}]

Comment: and parse t [ to {"} {"} copy x to {"} ]

Comment: What if I want to keep the " ?